# How to make nicer PHP urls

Tags: php, url, hyperlink, path, indexing

I would like to replace my links appeared in my page's adressbar.

Now the links have this format: http://mypage.com/index.php?page=contact
And I want this format: mypage.com/contact

How to do that?
(No links please, I need example.)

**Update:**

This is one possible solution that worked:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)?$ index2.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: You probably need to configure your web server for URL rewriting. What server are you using? mod_rewrite is a very popular module for doing this in Apache.

Comment: You can easily do that with htaccess rewrites.

Comment: Which PHP framework are you using? Most have this built-in. Rather than learning PHP or mod-rewrite, your time will be a lot more well spent learning a modern PHP framework such as Kohana, Laravel, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at htaccess and mod_rewrite.

You asked for no links, so I'll let you Google them yourself.

Once you have a chosen path, try it out and if you can't get it working come back with examples of what you've tried and in what way they didn't work.

Comment: RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)?$ index2.php?page=$1 [L]  
This worked. Thanks again.

Comment: If you update your original post with a description then you may get some bites...